# What is this aircraft seen over Southern California?

Tags: aircraft-identification, airplane

It looked similar in shape to the DH108 Swallow seen at the top of this website 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tailless_aircraft

The best likeness I have found online (except the wings were flat and what looks like 2 large engines could have been propellers but I don't think they were that large) is found here:

https://www.nbcnews.com/mach/mach/th...ays-ncna745806

It is the 3rd image from the top: "Dzyne's Blended Wing Body concept. Dzyne Technologies"

Comment: Do you not have a picture?  Can you give more details?  How many jet engines did you see?  Where was the jet engine located.  Approximately what was the length of the wingspan?

Comment: From the description it could be a [de Havilland Vampire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Vampire), or a derivative. It would be helpful to know where this sighting took place.

Comment: Are you certain that it was a jet?

Comment: Without more info it is impossible, but it might have been a canard of some kind. Google *Long EZ*, or *VariEze*, or *Berkut* and see if anyu of these look familiar.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it was a jet? Maybe it was some sort of [Rutan VariEze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutan_VariEze)?

[image: Rutan VariEze]

Comment: John Denver's crash coffin...  Actually a LongEze

Comment: That's not fair - it was actually a builder modified plane with the fuel selector placed above and behind a shoulder (in a  desire to keep fule lines out of the cabin I recall reading, vs standard locaiton of between the legs), and JD unfortunately pressed a rudder pedal, a natural enough motion, trying to reach up and back, causing an unintended roll and splash into the ocean.

Comment: .. and he was FUI, no ?

Comment: I doubt it. He had just taken possession and had been flying it for a while already that day.

Comment: No, I am not sure it was a jet and the closest picture I have found on the internet of a modern plane is the Beechcraft Starship.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be what you saw:

[image]

This is a Cirrus Vision SF50

Comment: Man that thing's ugly...

Comment: While it has V-tail I'm not sure that would look very strange when viewed from below.